# ProgressDialog in Android - Indicator shows full even for 30%

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to create a Progress Dialog as shown below in the code. 
But the problem is that when I hit cancel, and click on the progress bar(Edit:Display progress bar button) again, it doesn't work as expected. The indicator moves faster, and some times quits without even completing.

This is my code to call onClick3 when you click 'Click to Display...' button on the screen shot.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialogAdvanced;

public void onClick3(View v ){
    showDialog(1);
    progressDialogAdvanced.setProgress(0);
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 1; i <=10; i++){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    progressDialogAdvanced.incrementProgressBy((int)10);
                }catch(InterruptedException e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            progressDialogAdvanced.dismiss();
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

This is the code to create the progressbar:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch (id) {

case 1:
        progressDialogAdvanced = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialogAdvanced.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        progressDialogAdvanced.setTitle("Downloading...");
        progressDialogAdvanced.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialogAdvanced.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                        //progressDialogAdvanced.setProgress(0);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"OkClicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        progressDialogAdvanced.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            progressDialogAdvanced.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        return progressDialogAdvanced;
  }
}
```

[image: Indicator showing 100% right from 0 to 100]

Edit:

Used cancel() instead of dismiss(). Used Handler as shown below
Still doesn't fix anything. I have to wait till the thread gets destroyed.

```
for(int i = 1; i <=10; i++){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(500);                      
    }catch(InterruptedException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
    progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           progressDialogAdvanced.incrementProgressBy(10);
   }
    });
}
progressDialogAdvanced.cancel();
```

Comment: Is the `showDialog(1)` calling the static method `show` from the class `ProgressDialog` ?

Comment: Wow, is this code really working and not throwing an exception? Use a `Handler` maybe?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib It is working. And I used Handler as well, but even that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Create the handler on the main thread in your onClick using `final Handler mHandler = new Handler();` then inside your for loop replace `progressDialogAdvanced.incrementProgressBy((int)10);` by `mHandler.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {progressDialogAdvanced.incrementProgressBy((int)10);}});`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the maximum size of your progress like:

```
progressBar.setMax(100);
```

see this example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/

Comment: That didn't make any difference. After I click cancel, and start the dialog again, it sometimes quits even before 20%.. or move too fast.